# Opacity error in HTML

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

I need a opacity background and everything is working fine but when I add opacity to the background I can't use my bar. If you copy and paste the code you'll see everything with opacity but I can't use the bar buttons and I want only the background to be 0.5 opacity, not the whole website.

```css
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3KNQfA21QyQ/maxresdefault.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You had /style misspelled. Please fix the snippet I made for you - you need to put the tags into the correct order, you have many body tags. Also you have more spelling mistakes! shadow for example

Comment: How can i copy paste the code ??

Comment: Edit the snippet by clicking "edit snippet" and change the code to be valid HTML and valid CSS

Comment: Also your LIs have display:none... What are you trying to do?

Comment: i placed the whole code now.

Comment: Place the HTML into the HTML part of the snippet and the CSS in the CSS part. Then remove the `<body bgcolor="black">
<body class="my-container">
<div id="background"></div>` because they do not belong in the page - see what I did for you? Now at least we can see the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS it's "okay", the messed up it's on HTML. Try to rearrange this **body** before the whole structure first:

```
<body class="my-container" bgcolor="black">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">dropdown</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="background"></div>
</body>
```

Then, set the #background z-index to lower than your whole structure:

```
ul { position: relative; z-index: 3; }
#background { position: fixed; z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: No problem! Also, the "box-shadow" property was misspelled, take a look.

Comment: i got it from w3school

Comment: i just need it like this with the opacity background https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

Comment: yes, someone already fixed your css, just check into our first entry here ;) cya